# Sencha Touch 2: 'specified Store cannot be found'

Tags: sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I'm trying to load JSON data into a NestedList. I have the following store file in /app/store/Exhibits.js

```
Ext.define('VisitTCMIndy.store.Exhibits',{
requires: ['VisitTCMIndy.model.Exhibit', 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
config: {
    model: 'VisitTCMIndy.model.Exhibit',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://www.example.com/explore.php',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootPropery: 'children'
        }
    }   
}
});
```

Then I reference it in the following view in /app/view/Explore.js

```
Ext.define('VisitTCMIndy.view.Explore', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    'VisitTCMIndy.store.Exhibits',
],
xtype: 'explorecard',
config: {
    iconCls: 'compass1',
    title: 'Explore',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Explore'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'nestedlist',
            fullscreen: true,
            store: 'VisitTCMIndy.store.Exhibits',
            detailCard: {
                html: 'Explore Details'
            },
            listeners: {
                leafitemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, target, record){
                    var detailCard = nestedList.getDetailCard();
                    detailCard.setHtml('Exhibit Title: '+ record.get('title'));
                }
            }
        }

    ]
}
});
```

I get the following warning and an empty list when I go to the page:

> [WARN][Ext.dataview.NestedList#applyStore] The specified Store cannot be found

Fore the life of me, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. Turns out I had to declare my store and model in my app.js file. Then refer to my store just by it's name without the rest of the class definition. So, I added the following to my app.js file:

```
models: ['Exhibit'],
stores: ['Exhibits'],
```

Then, here's my updated Explore.js view file.

```
Ext.define('VisitTCMIndy.view.Explore', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    'VisitTCMIndy.store.Exhibits',
],
xtype: 'explorecard',
config: {
    iconCls: 'compass1',
    title: 'Explore',
    layout: 'vbox',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'titlebar',
            docked: 'top',
            title: 'Explore'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'nestedlist',
            store: 'Exhibits',
            title: 'Museum Levels',
            displayField: 'title',
            detailCard: {
                html: 'Explore Details'
            },
            listeners: {
                leafitemtap: function(nestedList, list, index, target, record){
                    var detailCard = nestedList.getDetailCard();
                    detailCard.setHtml('<div style="text-align:center;margin:.5em;"><img src="'+record.get('image')+'" alt="'+record.get('title')+'" />'+
                        '<p style="text-align:left;">'+record.get('text')+'</p></div>'
                    );
                }
            },
            flex: 1
        }

    ]
}
});
```

Also, notice I changed the layout from fit to vbox. I had to do this, and give the list a flex of 1 in order for the list to actually show now that it was loading the data.